# ASP.NET MVC3 Html.EditorFor and property of type object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm creating user control in MVC3 application. My view model looks like that:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

The Value property could be an int, string or bool so I can't use `[DataType]` attribute.

When I create my view model:

```
var viewModel = new MyViewModel { Value = "" };
```

or

```
var viewModel = new MyViewModel { Value = 1 };
```

I assume that this code:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(p => p.Value) %>
```

should render an HTML input of type textbox. Unfortunately nothing is being rendered.

Everything works fine when I use bool value or some not empty string. Here's an example:

```
var viewModel = new MyViewModel { Value = true };
```

`Html.EditorFor` renders checkbox input:

[image: Value property of type bool]

I did some research, but for now I didn't found solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used:

```
 <%: Html.Editor("Value") %>
```

instead of:

```
 <%: Html.EditorFor(p => p.Value) %>
```

and everything works great! The textbox is being rendered for empty string or int value. What is wrong with expression `p => p.Value`?

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer, but can't you just make your ViewModel generic:

```
public class MyViewModel<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

This way, the Html helper method can resolve at compile time exactly what type value is, and exactly which editor to render.

Comment: This is simplified example. In real app I have generic type - just like you said. But I need to be able to create list of `MyViewModel`. As you know I can't create list of generic types, so I created interface (`IMyViewModel`) with property `Value` of type object.