# ASP.NET MVC 5 Html.EditorFor and property of type object

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am creating a dynamic user control in MVC 5 application. My view model looks like this:

```
public class StoredProceduerParametersRecordViewModel
{
    public string ProcedureName { get; set; }
    public string ParameterName { get; set; }
    public string ServerName { get; set; }
    public object ParameterValue { get; set; }
    //public object NewParameterName { get; set; }
}
```

The NewParameterName could be an int, string, bool or any data type.

I am getting the NewParameterName values from Stored Procedure Parameters

```
List<StoredProcedureParameter> parameters = new List<StoredProcedureParameter>();
parameters = database.StoredProcedures[procedure.ProcedureName]
                     .Parameters.OfType<StoredProcedureParameter>()
                     .ToList();

foreach (var param in parameters)
{
    StoredProceduerParametersRecordViewModel obj_parameter =
    new StoredProceduerParametersRecordViewModel();

    obj_parameter.ParameterName = param.Name;
    obj_parameter.NewParameterName = CommonHelper.ConvertSmoToClsType(param.DataType.SqlDataType, string.Empty);
    stored_procedure_parameters_list.Add(obj_parameter);
 }
```

My CommonHelper.ConvertSmoToClsType looks like this:

```
public static object ConvertSmoToClsType(SqlDataType dataType, string currentValue)
{
   object Object = new object();

   switch (dataType)
   {
       case SqlDataType.BigInt:
       Object = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentValue)) ? (Int64)0 : Int64.Parse(currentValue);
       break;
       case SqlDataType.Bit:
       Object = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentValue)) ? (Boolean)false : Boolean.Parse(currentValue);
       break;
       case SqlDataType.Char:
       case SqlDataType.VarChar:
       case SqlDataType.VarCharMax:
       Object = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentValue)) ? String.Empty : currentValue;
       break;
       case SqlDataType.Real:
       case SqlDataType.Numeric:
       case SqlDataType.Float:
       Object = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentValue)) ? 0D : Double.Parse(currentValue);
       break;
       and so on...
    }
}
```

I am trying to use HTML.Editor to display user controls

```
@foreach (var obj in Model.List_StoredProceduresParametersRecords_ViewModel)
{
  <tr id="@obj.ParameterName">
      <td class="parameterName" data-value="@obj.ParameterName">@obj.ParameterName</td>
      <td>@Html.Editor("NewParameterName")</td>
  </tr>
}
```

I referenced my code using this link ---> [ASP.NET MVC3 Html.EditorFor and property of type object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837059/asp-net-mvc3-html-editorfor-and-property-of-type-object)
However, this solutions is not applicable for list.

How can I show the controls using Html.Editor or Html.EditorFor in my foreach loop?

Comment: I'm not actually seeing a *question* in this post? Just a bunch of code? Am I missing something?

Comment: The editor does not display the user control for that certain data type. What am I missing in my last code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EditorFor cannot ready empty strings so what I did was change this line of code.

```
Object = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentValue)) ? String.Empty : currentValue;
```

TO

```
Object = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentValue)) ? " " : currentValue;
```

I also changed my code from

```
<td>@Html.Editor("NewParameterName")</td>
```

TO

```
<td>@Html.EditorFor(model => obj.ParameterValue)</td>
```

It works now, except for my Double object. Do you have any ideas?